# Play Store APP publish

Tags: android

I have purchase the certificate for eclipse from play store and publish one Application that was made in eclipse.
Now I am working on android studio and publish app on old certificate.
Is this possible or not?

Comment: I am not getting what do want to say??

Comment: *I have purchase the certificate for eclipse from play store* what? did you meant I had pay registration fee?

Comment: yes you can, to publish your app you just need keystore and signed apk, it doesn't matter how and from where you have generated it. But make sure if you are updating app, keystore must be same.

Comment: hello ravi what is the use of sqllite??

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, Use the same keystore certificate file to sign the build on Android studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you have to use your old keystore file to build the sign APK.